# Download file in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, download

I have looked almost everywhere on the internet and I cannot find a way to download a file from the internet into a specific folder that works with VB.NET 2010. I would like to download a file called, for instance, example.txt, and download it into, for example, %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup so that it will run automatically at system startup. All help is appreciated

Comment: Wow, that would be perfect for malware!

Answer (score 3):

Guessing something based on...

```
Using webClient = New WebClient()
  Dim bytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://www.google.com")

  File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyFileName.ext"), bytes)
End Using
```

As for the startup, VB.NET has a pretty ease way to add Registry keys...

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue
```

To set something like HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run

**UPDATE**

How to: Create a Registry Key and Set Its Values in Visual Basic

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy6azwf7(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: The file is downloaded in bytes, and then you can store the data where ever you would like... modifed the example to get the specific special folder etc..

Comment: use 'Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup' to get the starup folder

Comment: here it is for VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx). Use [Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get the path to save the file.

```
Sub Main()

    Using wc As New WebClient()
        Dim startupPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
        wc.DownloadFile("http://MyDomain.com/MyFile.txt", Path.Combine(startupPath, "test.txt"))
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to Dispose the WebClient