# Magento CSV import , CSV file with full web address , Download the images

Tags: php, excel, magento, vba, csv

I am looking to download images from CSV , we have csv with full web address in that

example below
Colmun

1. www.xyz.com/abc.jpg
2. www.xyz.com/abc1.jpg
3. www.xyz.com/abc2.jpg

So it should download  the above images to specific location on my computer or to FTP location

Once it is downloaded then it must strip the full URL and make it in following way

1. /abc.jpg
2. /abc1.jpg
3. /abc2.jpg

I want to use this file with magento to import multiple images , with full URL but i know magento does not support multiple image or full URL

so i come up with above solution which can download full URL on computer and then i strip the URL and upload using magento import easily

Can any one has idea on this macro or script ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want CSV file to download images to your local drive??!!  A CSV file is just a text file holding comma separated values.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr , yes it is a text file , but consider it as a excel file , and one column has a images , so it will process that raw and download all images from that raw and store it to the local drive and then stripped off the www content and only keep the file name

Comment: Unlike excel,  you can't keep images in CSV.

Comment: Is it that you want someone to write a script that'll look at your CSV file, download the images and modify the url text to rremove all but the leading / character?  Try writing it yourself, post your code and people can help with the rough spots.

Comment: Mybe it would be worth starting [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Imoroved Import](http://firebearstudio.com/improved-import.html) extension for easy import products with multiple images directly from external URLs. This extension allow you just add new column for multiple product images and fill it with separated by , URLs.