# Download Embeded PDF file using VBA

Tags: html, vba, winhttp

I have word document containing hyperlinked text.
I want to go to that page and check if there is any embedded pdf.
If there is I want to download the PDF

Hyperlink looks like this

[http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?PageNum=0&docid=20150299141&homeurl=http\appft.uspto.gov](http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?PageNum=0&docid=20150299141&homeurl=http%5C%5Cappft.uspto.gov)

Most of the time link contains

```
<embed src="http://pimg-faiw.uspto.gov/fdd/41/2015/91/029/0.pdf"
       width="100%" height="850" type=application/pdf></embed>
```

Is there any way?
I am completely novice in VBA.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer

Comment: Thaks @HuguesPaquetBlanchette. Problem is My link is not directly downloading the file. I need to crawl withing HTML to find link to PDF.

Comment: XMLHTTP object will give you all http codes inside web page, where you can find link to the file and download it. Inside the response, after dynamically calling url,you can search for "<embed src"http://..." as in a string. If you fond it, download it. Hope this help. -Hugues

Comment: @HuguesPaquetBlanchette: I am new to Programming. I will try and post the answer if succed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked finally.

```
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
HttpReq.send
StrTxt = HttpReq.responseText
i = InStr(StrTxt, "http://pimg-faiw.uspto.gov/fdd")
If i > 0 Then
StrTxt = Mid(StrTxt, i, Len(StrTxt) - i)
i = InStr(StrTxt, ".pdf")
If i > 0 Then
myURL = Left(StrTxt, i + 3)
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.send
myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.Pdf", 2
    oStream.Close
End If
```

Comment: hi rahul can we have word? reach me at 9867711779