# Excel VBA: File Download works from Browser but program based method fails

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried all the solutions provided over here
[How do i download a file using VBA (Without internet explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)

However I am not able to download following file:
http://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/ATM/DOCs/AT1015D7D4F2BE7E4E412BBF4AB05C8A5DB585.XLS

It is public document and it can be easily downloaded using browser but I am not able to get it work in Excel VBA.

Here is the page containing the link
https://m.rbi.org.in/Scripts/ATMView.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you can use Workbooks.Open directly and open the file in Excel and then do a save-as?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I realized after reconciling HTTP request that although the link is http, it automatically redirects to https. So by just changing http to https in the link, it worked for me.

Thanks everyone.