# Downloading a file with WINHTTP using POST/GET and headers (with VBA)

Tags: html, vba, http-headers

As a follow up to my previous question: [Automating File Download of a link that looks like this: https://www.domain.com/TableData/TableA.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859488/automating-file-download-of-a-link-that-looks-like-this-https-www-domain-com)

I am learning more about headers that are sent with POST and GET - but I am far from knowing what I need to know.

The code I have so far works in downloading the file, but the problem from the last question is still persisting. When I open the downloaded file after execution it is filled with html of the login page as though the credentials did not work from the POST login. I suspect my problem lies in the strAuthenticate string, but I don't know for sure.

```
Sub SaveFileFromURL()

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim WHTTP As Object

fileUrl = "https://www.ncci.com/Manuals/RateTableData/State/XX/XX.csv"
filePath = "C:\Apps\information.csv"

myuser = "xxxxxx"
mypass = "xxxxxx"

strAuthenticate = "sm_userid=xxxxx&sm_password=xxxxxx"

Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

WHTTP.Open "POST", "https://www.ncci.com", False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send strAuthenticate
x = WHTTP.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

MsgBox x
WHTTP.Open "GET", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", x
WHTTP.send



FileData = WHTTP.responseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

FileNum = FreeFile
Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum

MsgBox "File has been saved!", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: There may also be a session cookie you'd need to set. Take a look there too.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your suggestion. I am still having the same issue, but now you make me wonder if I need to set all the cookies - since this site has multiple cookies. How do I set all of them?

Comment: See this question I asked on this very topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726408/retrieve-all-cookies-from-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIG THANK YOU TO RYAN WILDRY! Problem Solved.

I needed to set two specific cookies and change the actual login link - using the main domain was not working.

For anyone else who finds this post one day - Look through the cookies using the developer tools and find the ones that you need to pass on login. I personally tested them by having a message box with the response headers pop up which I compared to the response headers that I usually get when I login manually.