# Opening hyperlinks inside Excel with Powershell

Tags: excel, windows, powershell

I have a Excel sheet with about 600 rows with each row containing hyperlink to some downloadable file.

```
    #rowMax is the maxinum rows in the excel sheet
$rowMax = 99
$StartingColumnValue = 3
$StartingRowValue = 2
for ($StartingRowValue; $StartingRowValue -lt $rowMax+1; $StartingRowValue++){
    write-host $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartingRowValue,$StartingColumnValue).Text
}
```

So far I've managed to display the names of the hyperlinks, but I would like to actually "click" on them and download them.

How may I accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to download 600 items?

Comment: Yes, I would like to download all 600 files.

Comment: you can use the code on [How do i download a file using VBA (Without internet explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer) and feed each link into it using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you got the "name", I assume you got the link too.

Provided that it is the case, you could loop through the link and download them using the web client.

Here is a small example, extracting the filename from the URL (depending on the URL format, you might need to use another logic)

```
$WC = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$url = 'http://ec.ccm2.net/www.commentcamarche.net/download/files/SFDLC_v2.0_bin.zip'
$Filename = ($url.Split('/') | Select -Last 1)     

$wc.DownloadFile($url,"C:\__TMP\$Filename")
```

For alternative methods, take a look at this [article](https://powershellone.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/review-of-methods-to-download-files-using-powershell/).

If your file might be big and want some async method with progress, take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DBremen/425ad80bc0fb7d4ffd46#file-get-filewcasynchronous-ps1)

Comment: When I hover over my hyperlinks in the Excel sheet, a window pops up displaying the link(URL). How may I retrieve this URL using Powershell?

Comment: I managed to find all the URLs of the hyperlinks, I will try this method.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me. Had to do a little bit of modification but your wc.DownloadFile() is what I wanted.