# Importing a VBA module from the web

Tags: vba, excel

I succesfully created a VBA sub to import a VBA module from a local file with code like

```
sImportFile = "C:\temp\Module.bas"

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import sImportFile
```

For update reasons the file should be on the web, for example

```
sImportFile =  "http://mywebsite.org/download/Module.bas"
```

But then I'm getting a Path/File access error (Error 75). The download folder is not protected. How to import from an URL?

Comment: Download to local temporary folder, import and delete temporary file. `.Import` cannot download files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to import from an URL?

You don't. You download the file to your local file system, and provide `VBComponents.Import` with the path to the local file.

You can find out how to download a file from a URL with an HTTP request [right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877390/1188513).