# VBA code opens an unwanted browser window

Tags: excel, vba, browser, shapes

Got some issues with my code in VBA, downloading and inserting images to my Excel doc.

I have the following code in a loop:

```
Set theShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture( _
    Filename:=myurl, _
    linktofile:=msoFalse, _
    savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
    left:=left, _
    top:=top, _
    Width:=-1, _
    Height:=-1)
```

where "myurl" contains a link to the image, it works and the image is downloaded and inserted, but every time the code runs it opens a browser window and won't continue until the window is manually closed.

I start the Sub with:

```
With Application
.Cursor = xlWait
.DisplayStatusBar = True
.WindowState = xlMaximized
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.Interactive = False
.AskToUpdateLinks = False
.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False
End With
```

The browser window doesn't display the image but the login to the actual site. The image is accessible without login and looking at the headers through powershell I can see the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (wget https://www.deltaco.se/sites/cdn/PublishingImages/Products/hdmi-1022.jpg?width=80).Headers

Key                             Value
---                             -----
SPRequestGuid                   1042979e-00c5-c079-20f9-7d4f1f0a2f25
request-id                      1042979e-00c5-c079-20f9-7d4f1f0a2f25
X-FRAME-OPTIONS                 SAMEORIGIN
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices 15.0.0.4569
X-Content-Type-Options          nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp                  1; RequireReadOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin     *
Accept-Ranges                   bytes
Content-Length                  1669
Cache-Control                   public, max-age=86400
Content-Type                    image/jpeg
Date                            Thu, 11 Oct 2018 07:08:06 GMT
ETag                            "{73EDFF3E-4289-4D00-A2E8-B3D5C0E3565A},4rend79_1"
Last-Modified                   Tue, 09 Oct 2018 06:45:17 GMT
Server                          Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version                4.0.30319
X-Powered-By                    ASP.NET
```

And:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wget https://www.deltaco.se/sites/cdn/PublishingImages/Products/hdmi-1022.jpg?width=80


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {255, 216, 255, 224...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    SPRequestGuid: a942979e-a0b5-c079-20f9-788e9a1abf7c
                    request-id: a942979e-a0b5-c079-20f9-788e9a1abf7c
                    X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
                    MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
                    X-Con...
Headers           : {[SPRequestGuid, a942979e-a0b5-c079-20f9-788e9a1abf7c], [request-id, a942979e-a0b5-c079-20f9-788e9a1abf7c], [X-FRAME-OPTIONS, SAMEORIGIN], [MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices, 15.0.0.4569]...}
RawContentLength  : 1669
```

*(Powershell got nothing to do with the issue, just used it to check the headers)*

I can't see any redirects or other reason for the code to open a browser window.

How can I prevent the browser window to open at all?

Comment: I recommend to download the file first (to temporary folder) and then insert it in Excel. See [How do I download a file using VBA (Without internet explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow Anders

If the image is accessible without url then you can use the API `URLDownloadToFile`

See this example. I have commented the code. If you still have a problem understanding it, let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub Sample()
    Dim myurl As String, tempFilePath As String
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    '~~> Img URL
    myurl = "https://www.deltaco.se/sites/cdn/PublishingImages/Products/hdmi-1022.jpg"

    '~~> Get user temp path and the image name from the above url
    '~~> For exmaple C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\hdmi-1022.jpg
    tempFilePath = TempPath & GetFilenameFromURL(myurl)

    '~~> Download the image and save it as tempFilePath
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, myurl, tempFilePath, 0, 0)

    If Ret = 0 Then
        '~~> File successfully downloaded
        '~~> Add the shape
        Set theShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture( _
                       Filename:=tempFilePath, _
                       linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                       savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                       Left:=10, _
                       Top:=10, _
                       Width:=-1, _
                       Height:=-1)

        DoEvents

        '~~> Delete the img file in the temp directory
        Kill tempFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to download the file"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Function to get user temp directory
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function

'~~> Function to get Image name from URL
Function GetFilenameFromURL(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "/" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromURL = GetFilenameFromURL(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```