# VBA - Unable to open worksheet while VBA is running

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems with Opening a worksheet while VBA is running (as Excel/VBA is occupied, it prevents another sheet opening as far as I'm aware).

```
SendKeys ("%O")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)


'Loop that waits for file to open
Dim TestWorkbook As Workbook
Set TestWorkbook = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set TestWorkbook = Workbooks("export.csv")

OpenLoop:
If TestWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    GoTo OpenLoop
Else
End If
'Loop that waits for file to open (End)

Workbooks("export.csv").Activate
```

`SendKeys ("%O")` is used to open the file on Internet Explorer as below:

[image]

If the code ended here, it will open successfully as VBA has finished.
Now, it just get stuck in the loop because VBA being busy is preventing the file to open.

**Problem: I need a solution to allow the file to open so the VBA can continue and work on the downloaded folder.**

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Avoid using `Sendkey` if possible. This is not very reliable and a bad practice. If you want to download (and open) a file from a website use something like the following approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877390/3219613

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Hello PEH. I'm unable to get a directly link to the downloaded file. I'm working with a company program and the 'link' on the export (download) button is the same as the web browser. I'm unable to see how I implement this code. I'm not the best with VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Try commenting out your 'TestLoop' code lines, from `Open to End If` and then run your code.

Comment: Swap statements: Set TestWorkbook = Workbooks("export.csv") and 

OpenLoop:

Comment: @jkpieterse better to use a real loop instead of an ugly and bad practice `Goto`. See my anwser.

Comment: @PEH: Good point :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `Set TestWorkbook = Workbooks("export.csv")` results in `Nothing` then the following code will loop for ever

```
OpenLoop:
If TestWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    GoTo OpenLoop
Else
End If
```

because you never try to `Set TestWorkbook` to something again.

So better use something like that:

```
Dim TestWorkbook As Workbook
Set TestWorkbook = Nothing

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TestWorkbook = Workbooks("export.csv")
    On Error Goto 0 'always re-activate error reporting!!!
    ' you can add a wait here but it's not necessarily needed.
    DoEvents 'keep Excel responsive (in case of endless loop)
Loop While TestWorkbook Is Nothing
```

Note that this loop will run until `export.csv` is open. If it will never open this will run forever. So probably you want to insert a time criteria to cancel the loop after some amount of time eg. 1 minute.

Note that `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)` is not necessarily needed. The loop will just re-try to find the workbook until it is there, even without wait.