# Download zip file from web using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am new to excel and I am following [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/need-vba-to-download-and-copy-the-data-from-zip-file.984206/) to download zip file using excel vba.

```
        UrlFile = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2020/MAR/cm13MAR2020bhav.csv.zip"
        On Error GoTo exit_
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
         .Open "GET", UrlFile, False
         .setRequestHeader "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"
         .setRequestHeader "Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document"
         .send
        If .Status <> 200 Then Exit Function
        b() = .responseBody
        FN = FreeFile
        Open PathName For Binary Access Write As #FN
        Put #FN, , b()
    exit_:
         MsgBox Err.Description
        If FN Then Close #FN
        Url2File = .Status = 200
      End With
```

On executing **.send** in above code, it always results in the error **"The download of specified resource has failed"** .Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download a file using VBA (without Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)

Comment: I have used 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' also and my code is similar to the code in the given link. But I am getting error the download has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2020/MAR/cm13MAR2020bhav.csv.zip"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\praburaj\Downloads\file.zip", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Function
```