# Using VBA To Gather Zipped Files From A Website, Open Them, Extract Excel Files and Copy Them Into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I am currently trying to extract an excel file from a website and upload it into an excel worksheet using VBA. The link to where the data can be found is at the following link:

http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12301&reportTitle=Settlement%20Point%20Prices%20at%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Hubs%20and%20Load%20Zones&showHTMLView=&mimicKey

The issue I am facing is that the excel files are located within Zip files. I eventually would like to use VBA to download all of the zip files found at that link and compile all of the excel files they contain into one single worksheet, but for now I just want to download one file.

If you can help me use VBA to download the first zip file included in the link listed above, open the zip file, extract the excel file from the zip file, extract the data from the excel file, and paste that data into another excel worksheet, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this issue!

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link. I have reviewed it, and it has allowed me to move downloaded zip files into one folder. My issue is still that I would like to be able to automate the process of downloading a zip file from the website I provided in my initial question and then unzip that file and upload the contents of that zip file into one folder ( I believe the link you provided will allow me to complete the process after I download the files from the website). Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad - more of a project than a question, so it's not clear what the specific problem is.  What exactly is preventing you from doing this? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: I do not know how to automate the process of downloading a zip file from the following link. <http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12301&reportTitle=Settlement%20Point%20Prices%20at%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Hubs%20and%20Load%20Zones&showHTMLView=&mimicKey> As you can see when you go to the site, there are csv and xml files located within zip files. I believe that if I can automate the process of downloading a zip file from that site, I will be able to do the rest. I apologize if I am being confusing. I am new to VBA and not familiar with it at all. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For automatc download of a file, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for!