# Download a zip in a local server

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download a zip in a local server using VBA.

My code works in my PC. At the server I always have "Download failed".

Cell A7 is the link of the download.

```vb
Dim downloadStatus As Variant
Dim url As String
Dim destinationFile_local As String

url = [A7]
destinationFile_local = "C:\Users\omayorga\Downloads\" & fileName([A7])

downloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, destinationFile_local, 0, 0)

If downloadStatus = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Downloaded Succcessfully!"
Else
    MsgBox "Download failed"
End If

End Sub

Function fileName(file_fullname) As String
    fileName = Mid(file_fullname, InStrRev(file_fullname, "/") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" looks like what exactly?

Comment: Doesn't download the file

Comment: So you just get a message "Download failed" ?  Are you able to manually download the file on the server eg. using a browser?

Comment: I have that condition and alwalys show me that "Download failed"

Comment: Does the local server have this folder? `C:\Users\omayorga\Downloads`

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your code, you need:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
```

Check your download link, the same said Raymond Wu your destinationFile_local, tested here your code works.

refer link

> [How do I download a file using VBA (without Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)